# Javascript - Extract part of a string lying between two special characters

Tags: javascript, url

I have strings like these-

```
countries=a,b&states=c,d&districts=e,f,g,h
countries=a,b
```

I want to extract the part of the string which is lying between the characters `=` and `&` and return the result as an array. So, in the first case, the result should be `['a','b', 'c','d','e','f','g','h']`. In the second case, it should be `['a','b']`. I achieved the result by doing like this-

```
const extract = string.split('&');
const splitArray = extract.map(x => x.split('=')[1]);
const resultString = splitArray.join(',');
const result = resultString.split(',');
```

Can I do it more concisely and in a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One example using [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

```
let query = 'countries=a,b&states=c,d&districts=e,f,g,h';
let values = [];

(new URLSearchParams(query)).forEach(function(v) { 
    v.split(',').forEach(function(v){
        values.push(v);
    });
});

console.log(values); // ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]
```

... but if by "concise" you mean "one-liner" .. well here's my take:

```
let query = 'countries=a,b&states=c,d&districts=e,f,g,h';

query = query.replace(/(^|&).*?=/g,',').split(',').filter(Boolean);

console.log(query); // ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const input = [
  'countries=a,b&states=c,d&districts=e,f,g,h',
  'countries=a,b'
];
input.forEach((line) => {
  let result = [].concat.apply([], line
    .split(/&/)
    .map((keyValue) => {
      return keyValue.replace(/^[^=]*=/, '').split(/,/)
    }));
  console.log(line + ' ==> ' + JSON.stringify(result));
});
```

Output:

```
countries=a,b&states=c,d&districts=e,f,g,h ==> ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h"]
countries=a,b ==> ["a","b"]
```

Explanation:

- split by `&` to get key/value pairs
- for each key/value:

  - extract the value
  - split the value by `'`
- flatten the resulting array of arrays with `[].concat.apply([], arr)`

Alternatively you could initialize an empty array `[]`, and as a last step of for each key/value, do a forEach on each item, and push it to the array.